# Creating a NuGet package for UWP library containing custom Templated Control

Tags: nuget, uwp-xaml

I have a UWP class library for Windows 10 which contains a custom templated control, **VisualControl**. The default template is defined in the **Themes\Generic.xaml** file.

Here is the directory structure I have created for the NuGet package which targets x86, x64 and ARM.

[image: Nuget Directory structure]

When I creat a NuGet package with these files, add it to my test application and add the VisualControl to the XAML file, the default theme is not applied to the VisualControl.
Am I packaging the file in an incorrect way? How do I ensure that the default template defined in the Generic.xaml file is picked up and applied to the Control.
Also, are the following files required in the NuGet package? If yes, where should they be placed?

- **Generic.xbf**
- **TestVisualControl.pri**
- **TestVisualControl.xr.xml**

Answer (score 1):

Found out the solution.

- The **Generic.xbf** file should be placed in the **Themes** folder along with **Generic.xaml**.
- The **TestVisualControl.xr.xml** file should be placed in a folder named **TestVisualControl**. This folder should be placed inside **uap10.0** folder of each platform.
- The **TestVisualControl.pri** should be placed inside the **uap10.0** folder of each platform.

Here is what the final folder structure should look like

[image: Nuget Folder structure]

Creating a NuGet package with this folder structure would ensure that the style defined in the **Generic.xaml** file is loaded.